# Как закрыть приложение Qt из другой формы?

Tags: c++, qt, form

пробовал свой сигнал создавать но не помогло. ниже немного кода:

dialog.h

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QString>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;

signals:
    void Ok(QString name);
    void Exit();
private slots:
    void on_pushButtonOk_clicked();
    void on_pushButtonExit_clicked();
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>
#include <dialog.h>
#include <QString>


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QLabel labelAll;
    QLabel labelRight;
    QLabel labelError;

    Dialog dialog; // вторая формочка

    QString name;

    char RigthReply;
    int TotalQuest;
    int CurrentQuest;
    int theRight;
    int theError;

    void TotalQuests();
    void GetQuest(int num);
private slots:
    void SetName(QString s);
    void on_pushButtonA_clicked();
    void on_pushButtonB_clicked();
    void on_pushButtonV_clicked();
    void on_pushButtonG_clicked();
    void on_action_3_triggered();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

связывание делаю в конструкторе основной формы:
mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QObject::connect(&dialog, SIGNAL(Ok(QString)), this, SLOT(SetName(QString)));
    QObject::connect(&dialog, SIGNAL(Exit()), this, SLOT(close()));

    dialog.exec();

........
```

сам сигнал Exit() генерирую в деструкторе второй формы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
...
QObject::connect(&dialog, SIGNAL(Exit()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
```

**Update:**
В общем случае не стоит вызывать диалог в конструкторе главной формы. Выделите для этого отдельный слот, который вызывайте через очередь:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "showMyDialog", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

В слоте напишите просто что-то вроде такого:

```
void MainWindow::showMyDialog() {
   if(MyDialog(this).exec() == QDialog::Rejected)
      qApp->quit();
}
```

Вместо "QDialog::Rejected" можно использовать любой иной флаг по ситуации.

Если же Вам нужно, чтобы главное окно не показывалось до вывода диалога, то операцию вызова диалога перенесите в main.cpp или иной управляющий модуль.

Comment: не помогло та же самая ситуация

Comment: Проверьте, что сигнал "Exit()" у Вас точно отправляется.

Comment: только что проверил. написал свой слот в главной форме. он нормально отрабатывает

Comment: Тогда скорее всего проблема в том, что диалог через вызов exec() работает собственной очереди событий и отсыл на выход из программы попросту игнорируется. Попробуйте сделать иначе. Метод exec() у диалога имеет возможность возвращать результат работы. Обычны его привязывают к одному из значений: QDialog::Accepted или QDialog::Rejected.

И, кстати, вызов диалога происходит в конструкторе главной формы, что также не вполне корректно.

Comment: причину нашел. если делать для диолога не exec() а open() все работает. те получается пока основная форма не открыта закрытие формы не возможно. не знаю что и делать. может вторую форму как то модальной можно сделать? мне нужно чтобы сначала первая форма появилась а только потом уже основная

Comment: Вообще, вместо open() лучше show() использовать. Метод show() вызовет диалог асинхронно в очереди событий приложения, не создавая при этом собственной. В обновлении к ответу я написал, что если Вам нужно показывать диалог до главного окна, то вызов диалога (с использованием exec() ) перенесите в main.cpp, а там уже, в зависимости от того результата, что вернёт диалог, показывайте главное окно, либо закрывайте программу посредством, например, "return 0;" из функции main().

Comment: все спасибо все решилось вызовом метода show() с указанием модальности в конструкторе моего второго окна